# cordova InAppBrowser plugin build error

Tags: android, cordova

I used `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` to open links in system browser.

but when I compile my app I get the following error :

> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class CordovaHttpAuthHandler
>   location: package org.apache.cordova

I uninstall and install it again but I get the same error.

cordova info :

```
c:\>cordova -v
6.0.0

c:\>cordova plugin list
com.lampa.startapp 0.0.6 "startApp"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
```